# How can a block IP addresses using Windows Server 2008 firewall?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, blocking

I have started to get various login attempts from different IP addresses.
How can I block these IP addresses in the Windows Server 2008 Firewall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows firewall (Win+R and wf.msc :P) create new custom inbound rule... You can set there whatever you want (protocol, ports, local and remote ip's).